# .Net error CS1514 when building application at Docker

Tags: docker, enums, .net-5

I have a .NET5 project with a file Enum.cs like this:

```html
namespace App.Enums;
public enum Enum1
{   
    Item1 = 0,
    Item2 = 1,
    Item3 = 2,
    Item4 = 3,
    Item5 = 4
}
```

When I try to run:

```html
 RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out
```

I receive the error:

```html
Enum.cs(3,27): error CS1514: { expected
```

The project builds normally outside Docker at Windows 11. How can I build it inside Docker?

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that if I change the class to this format the problem is solved:

```html
namespace App.Enums
{
  public enum Enum1
  {   
    Item1 = 0,
    Item2 = 1,
    Item3 = 2,
    Item4 = 3,
    Item5 = 4
  }
}
```

Another solution is using the .net 6.0 SDK.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with building in a docker container, while locally in vs studio everything ran fine. The project was Net 3.1 core on roslyn 3.1. Instead of enum there was the class.

Also, file-scoped syntax was not supported.

I had to change it to the old syntax.

```
namespace App.Class

{
   public class Class1
   {
     public Class1(){ }
     ...
   }
}
```